# Using OC4J Server Adapter with Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, oc4j

After banging my head against the wall for awhile (trying to figure out how to set up an OC4J server adapter in Eclipse), I finally realized that Eclipse Kepler has retired all 
support for the Oracle generic OC4J server adapter.  Is there anyway to manually install the server adapter for use with Eclipse Kepler?  Unfortunately, I am limited in my options, and am required to use the OC4J Oracle Containers.

If I can't directly work with the server in Eclipse Kepler, is there an easy way to deploy the application for testing purposes?  I know you can export it to an EAR file and deploy it manually, but would love to find a quicker way for me to easily test the application when making changes.

Thanks for your help!

-Laura

Answer (score 2):

You should use the maven-cargo plugin and see if it is of use to you. It supports OC4J quick deploy and would allow you to copy your target folder to the OC4J runtime.

[Maven Cargo Plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin)

Another quick and dirty way which i just tried is using the maven-antrun-plugin to specify ant tasks and tie them to a phase and copy them to wherever as needed.

```
             <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copydir src="src/main/webapp"
                                    dest="f://temp" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

It isnt perfect, but you get the idea, that you can do something like this and tie it to a phase and execute the goal to get your webapp directory in your OC4J deployable directory.

The cargo plugin would definately be something you should look at considering it has much more capabilities of starting and stopping the server runtime as well.

Comment: thanks! I'm going to try this out now...I'll get back soon to let you know how it goes.  I'm glad to hear that there is a way to get around the deprecated server connection.